# Hornetq with apache naming JNDI

Tags: apache, queue, jms, hornetq

I tried to put Apache JNDI for Hornetq according to these blog : http://wash-inside-out.blogspot.com/2010/08/hornetq-jms-integration-with-tomcat.html. but I'm getting this error now :

```
Deployment "Naming" is in error due to: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory  [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory ]
```

How to find out which jar file has that class?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this search result](http://findjar.com/class/org/apache/naming/java/javaURLContextFactory.html) in FindJar, naming-factory-5.5.23.jar is the one that contains that class. Beware that the dependency scope is test in the example you provided. Are you doing the lookup in non test code?